# Transit question from Dubai to Chennai

Tags: transit, short-connections, dubai

I am traveling from Houston, USA to Chennai, India. I have a one hour connect time in Dubai, UAE. Is this sufficient? What would be the procedure in Dubai airport?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Questions about tight connections are difficult to answer without knowing 1) which airlines are operating each leg of the flight, and 2) whether you booked your IAH-DXB and DXB-MAA flights on a single reservation or as two separate ones. Please [edit] your post to incorporate this information.

Answer (score 1):

In principle 1 hour is enough in Dubai (else the airline would not have sold you the ticket). But there is a high probability that your flight will be delayed and you will miss your connection.
Whether this risk is acceptable depends on the airline you are flying with and your exact arrival time in Dubai. As there are many flights from Dubai to Chennai, and you may have booked with a reputable carrier they will rebook you causing an acceptable delay.
Do not do this if you have two independent tickets or if buying the ticket from an obscure airline or travel website. To asses what obscure is we would need the details of your ticket (you can safely share everything accept your booking code and name).